# Alter table to get day name only from existing data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with a `datetime` column from which I need to extract the name of the day only and add to a new column like `dayNameOnly` and as default there after.

I have done the same to get the DATEONLY like this, but I cannot get it working with the datename or datepart.

```
ALTER TABLE someTable 
    ADD dayNameOnly AS CAST(DATEADD(DAY, DATADIFF(DAY, 0, someDateColounm), 0) as DATE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You wanted the weekday name in string ?

```
ALTER TABLE someTable 
ADD dayNameOnly 
As datename(weekday, someDateColounm)
```

On the query that you have shown, you do not need to perform the `dateadd/datediff` calculation `CAST(DATEADD(DAY, DATADIFF(DAY, 0, someDateColounm), 0) as DATE)`. You can simply `cast() or convert()` it to `date`

```
CAST(someDateColounm as DATE)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to add computed column `somedatecolumn`. Here's the script.

```
alter table someTable 
add dayNameOnly 
As cast(dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, someDateColounm), 0) as date)
```

**or,** if you want to extract the `weekday` name as a computed column.

```
alter table someTable 
add dayNameOnly
as datename(dw, someDateColounm)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #mytbl
(mydate  as DATENAME(WEEKDAY,getdate()),sno int)


insert into #mytbl(sno)
values (1)

select * from #mytbl
```